# script in elasticsearch range definition

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to keep the "to" param in the date range to be 
now + 5h if now is < now+ 5h otherwise keep it as now

I am unable to do date math as shown below in the "to" field for date range, so whats the best to achieve this, can I use script in the "to" field

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/cars/transactions/_search?pretty' -d '{
"query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "errorcount": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "sold",
                "ranges": [
                    {
                        "from": "now/d+5h",
                        "to": "now<now/d+5h?now+5h:now"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggs": {
                "errs": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "make",
                        "size": 5,
                        "order": {
                            "_count": "desc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: How could that be possible to have `now < now+ 5h`? Please explain your constraint in more details.

Comment: My mistake it was a typo, what I meant was now < now/d+5h